# VM missing in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-machine

I created an Ubuntu server vm using Visual Studio Subscription, 5 days ago. It is not a spot instance. I am able to ssh/rdp into it, and can also see it is billed daily, so I know it is up. However, I cannot find the VM on the list of virtual machines. The list is empty.

The issue is [similar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/30451/my-linux-vm-can-not-be-found-under-the-virtual-mac.html) to this question, where the accepted answer suggests it is a known issue and either to clear the browser cache (did not work) or to send a request to Microsoft support (requires $29/month support subscription). Googling the issue, it seems the issue was present as early as [2014](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/e2a2534d-859c-430c-b37f-02a3bbb3855a/my-virtual-machines-disappeared-from-the-portal-but-it-is-working?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows), so surely Microsoft has fixed it by now.

Answer (score 0):

This happens a lot to my cloud users... Make sure your subscription filter for your view is selecting all available subscriptions. While you're there, clear any filters on the view.

I've also seen this happen once when the user who created the resource left the company. We needed a super-admin to update the resource owner to someone currently at the company.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have double checked that the subscription is selected (I only have one) and filters show all locations, all types, all tags etc. But still no luck.

Comment: Sounds like you might need to open up a support ticket.

Comment: Try looking for the resource at resources.azure.com. That's the backend for the portal and I believe that's how we moved the owner ID the last time I hit this.

Comment: I can see everything else, e.g. the attached disk (which says managed by the vm), network security group, keys etc. except the vm itself. Same as the portal. I will look if there is a way to create a ticket without paying. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot create a support ticket. It is part of VS subscription from corporate account, and if I try add developer support $29/month, it asks for credit card instead of using subscription credit. Doesn't surprise to find this feedback from users on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/devops/comments/9dba9j/azure_users_whats_your_honest_overall_opinion_of/

Comment: For anyone interested, I had to reach out to @AzureSupport via twitter to get help. They mentioned that there was nothing I did wrong, but sometimes their back-end does not sync with front-end, and required to be manually synced.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the update! That's the first I've heard of that.